# iterate through rows and columns in excel using pandas-Python 3

Tags: excel, python-3.x, loops, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet that I read with this code:

```
df=pd.ExcelFile('/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/table.xlsx')
ccg=df.parse("CCG")
```

With the sheet that I want inside the spreadsheet being `CCG`

The sheet looks like this:

```
  col1  col2   col3    
x    a     1      2     
x    b     3      4    
x    c     5      6     
x    d     7      8
x    a     9      10
x    b     11     12
x    c     13     14
y    a     15     16
y    b     17     18
y    c     19     20
y    d     21     22
y    a     23     24
```

How would I write code that gets values of `col 2` and `col3` for rows that contain both `a` and `x`. So the proposed output for this table would be: `col1=[1,9]`, `col2=[2,10]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/table.xlsx', 'CCG', index_col=0, usecols=['col1','col2']) \
       .query("index == 'x' and col1 == 'a'")
```

Demo:

Excel file:

[image]

```
In [243]: fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\41718085.xlsx'

In [244]: pd.read_excel(fn, 'CCG', index_col=0, usecols=['col1','col2']) \
            .query("index == 'x' and col1 == 'a'")
Out[244]:
  col1  col2
x    a     1
x    a     9
```

Comment: its coming up with a syntax error on the `new=` line

Comment: You forgot to chain `.parse("CCG")`.

Comment: @MaxU, SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/table.xlsx'),sheetname='CCG', index_col=0)
filter = df[(df.index == 'x') & (df.col1 == 'a')]
```

Then from here, you can return all the values as a numpy array with:

```
filter['col2']
filter['col3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to create a `count`  that iterates until it finds `a` adds +1 to the `count` and only appends to the list `index` if it is between the ranges that x is in, once i have the indices i search through col 2 and 3 and pull the values out for the indices